# SubString in Ansible and/or Jinja2

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I'm trying to unmout all mountpoints, excepted if they are part of the current list:

```yaml
excluded: ['home', 'cdrom', 'tmpfs', 'sys', 'run', 'dev', 'root']
```

Sample fstab only devices:

- /dev/mapper/vgroot-local_home
- devtmpfs
- tmpfs

`/dev/mapper/vgroot-local_home` should be excluded from unmounting because the substring `home` is present on the array and the same for `devtmpfs` substring `tmpfs`. For `tmpfs` we have a perfect match. The goal is to check against devices.

After checking all [Ansible filters](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html) and the [Jinja2 documentation](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/), I didn't find a solution to this problem. All Ansible facts are collected.

```yaml
- name: Ensure the mountpoint is on the excluded list
  ansible.posix.mount:
    path: '{{ mount.device }}'
    state: unmounted
  when: {{ ??? }}
  with_items: '{{ ??? }}'
  become: true
  tags: mountpoints
```

Comment: I don't understand if you want to match your excludes on the device or the mount point name. Moreover, you say you gathered facts but you give an output of fstab so we don't have an example data structure. Please read [How to ask](/help/how-to-ask) and [Creating a minimal, complete and verifiable example](/help/mcve), then [edit](/posts/72346000/edit) your question to add the required information, more specifically what you have already tried, the result you get and the exact problem you are facing with your code and a precise example of what you expect instead.

Comment: The goal is to check against devices.

Answer (score 3):

To test if a string contains a substring in Jinja, we use the `in` test, much like Python:

```
"somestring" in somevariable
```

In your case, you want to check if a given string contains any substring from the `excluded` list. Conceptually, what we want is something like the Python expression

```
if any(x in mount.device for x in excluded)
```

Using Jinja filters, we need to reverse our logic a little bit.  We
can use the `select` filter to get a list of strings from the
`excluded` list that are contained in a given target string (such as
`mount.device`) like this:

```
excluded|select('in', item)
```

If `item` matches anything in the `excluded` list, the above
expression will result in a non-empty list (which evaluates to `true`
when used in a boolean context).

Used in a playbook, it would look like this:

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    excluded: ['home', 'cdrom', 'tmpfs', 'sys', 'run', 'dev', 'root']
    mounts:
      - /dev/mapper/vgroot-local_home
      - devtmpfs
      - tmpfs
      - something/else
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "unmount {{ item }}"
      when: not excluded|select('in', item)
      loop: "{{ mounts }}"
```

The above playbook produces as output:

```
TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
skipping: [localhost] => (item=/dev/mapper/vgroot-local_home) 
skipping: [localhost] => (item=devtmpfs) 
skipping: [localhost] => (item=tmpfs) 
ok: [localhost] => (item=something/else) => {
    "msg": "unmount something/else"
}
```

That is, it skips the task when the current loop item contains a
substring from the `excluded` list.

Assuming that your goal is "unmount all filesystems except those for
which the device name contains a substring from the `excluded` list",
you might write:

```
- name: Unmount filesystems that aren't excluded
  ansible.posix.mount:
    path: '{{ mount.device }}'
    state: unmounted
  when: not excluded|select('in', item.device)
  loop: "{{ ansible_mounts }}"
  become: true
  tags: mountpoints
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterate [*basename*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#managing-file-names-and-path-names) if you don't want to exclude the items of *mounts* because of matching the path, e.g. if you don't want to exclude *`/dev/mapper/vgroot-local_home`* because of *`dev`* in the *excluded* list

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "Unmount {{ item }}"
      loop: "{{ mounts|map('basename') }}"
      when: not excluded|select('in', item)
```